# LINQ to Entities does not recognize ToString using query syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm getting this error in a LINQ query (query syntax used). In the past I've gotten this error when using dot syntax in my LINQ query so all I had to do is a call to ToList() and then select using an anonymous class. But in my case where I'm now using query syntax, how do I do the same thing? Yes I'm using EF.

Here is the code:

```
            var dataList = from h in context.Horaires
            join e in context.Employes on h.iIdEmploye equals e.iIdEmploye
            join p in context.Postes on h.iIdPoste equals p.iIdPoste
            join g in context.GroupesPostes on p.iIdGroupePoste equals g.iIdGroupePoste
            join en in context.EnsemblesPostes on g.iIdEnsemblePoste equals en.iIdEnsemblePoste
            join d in context.Departements on e.iIdDepartement equals d.iIdDepartement
            where p.bitActif == true && h.dteDate == p.dteDate
            orderby e.sIdEmployeClient
            select new ScenarioScheduleItemModel
            {
                H = "D",
                EmployeeSchedule = "EmployeeSchedule",
                EmployeeSchedule2 = "EmployeeSchedule",
                EmployeeXrefCode = e.sIdEmployeClient,
                // ToString used here for StartTime and EndTime
                StartTime = h.dteDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(0, 10) + "T" + p.dteHeureDebut.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(11, 8),
                EndTime = h.dteDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(0, 10) + "T" + p.dteHeureFin.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(11, 8),
                DeptXrefCode = d.sNom,
                JobXrefCode = p.sNom,
                OrgUnit = string.Empty,
                XrefCode = string.Empty,
                OrgLocationTypeXrefCode = string.Empty,
                PayAdjCodeXrefCode = string.Empty
            };

        var result = dataList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Do you still get the issue when you don't pass "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" as an argument?

Comment: You could just select the date and the two times then using `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` and then a new `Select` to translate to what you need.

Comment: The problem is I don't know where to put the ToList() when using this type of query syntax. Secondly, I lose the variables h in h.dteDate when I do the second select in the anonymous class.

Comment: Both answers below are only partially correct. Call `AsEnumerable`() first. Then construct strings using `String.Format()`.

Comment: @Ray When including things in your linq to sql query where it cannot be translated to sql, you should first turn to list and then do another query on the list to do the conversions you want. Since the linq on list is not translated to sql, you will be allowed to do what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just select the "raw" values then use `AsEnumerable` and a `Select` to get the desired values

```
var dataList = (from h in context.Horaires
               ...
               select new { e, h, p, d }).AsEnumerable()
               .Select(anon => new ScenarioScheduleItemModel
               {
                   ...
                   StartTime = anon.h.dteDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                   .Substring(0, 10) 
                        + "T" + anon.p.dteHeureDebut.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                    .Substring(11, 8),
                   EndTime = anon.h.dteDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                 .Substring(0, 10) 
                        + "T" + anon.p.dteHeureFin.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                    .Substring(11, 8),
                   ...
               });
```

Comment: You may want to use String.Format or StringBuilder and do not concatenate string directly.

Comment: `string.Format` would problably be better.  I don't see how using a `StringBuilder` here would make any sense.  I mainly was trying to show the OP how to switch from linq that will be translated into SQL to linq that will be run in code allowing for a wider range of .Net functionality.

Comment: String.Format uses StringBuilder internally which is the fastest way to construct a string to my knowledge.

Comment: Also I would use the extension method syntax everywhere, do not mix it with the query syntax.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I didn't realize you can do a query-style select and then a subsequent .Select afterwards using the dot syntax. This worked! Thanks @juharr

Answer (score 0):

It may make more sense to use something like string.Format

```
StartTime = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}T{1:hh:mm:ss}", h.dteDate, p.dteHeureDebut),
EndTime = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}T{1:hh:mm:ss}", h.dteDate, p.dteHeureFin),
```

Comment: That would not work as the OP is using Entity Framework that is translating to SQL and `string.Format` is not supported.

Comment: you can use string.Format in a linq query.  He is doing a select which is a projection and allows for using string.format

Comment: The OP is using EF.  That will translate the query to SQL and has limited support for what it can translate.  That's why `ToString` isn't working.

Comment: According to this blog http://donovanbrown.com/post/2014/12/24/How-to-use-stringFormat-with-LINQ-Select just need to call ToArray or I am sure ToList would work prior to making the select.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that the time was from a different column.  That is my bad in the example.  I assumed it was a datetime object as Linq to Entities should probably add that map and he was using ToString().  Need more info on types etc from the OP I guess.

Comment: string.Format is not supported. I tried it, didn't work.

Comment: Will work fine but first you need put data in memory by calling AsEnumerable or ToArray, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your info. here's a generic form what you need to do:

```
var dbQuery = from x in db.Table
              // do stuff with x what will be translated to SQL
              select x;

var memoryQuery = from z in dbQuery.AsEnumerable() // <-- !
                  // do stuff with z in memory
                  select z;
```